# Program to automatically read Terms and Conditions

Tags: gratis, windows-7, automation, nlp, privacy

I am looking for a program that reads terms and conditions and shows me the sections that are privacy and tracking related.

Requirements:

- free
- automatically detects when terms and conditions are on screen (optional, but preferable)
- shows me the main parts ***related to privacy and tracking***
- run on Windows 7 64 bit

This is basically because it is becoming more and more important to know what you are signing up to nowadays - especially people like Google and Apple, who track everything you do on your phone and computer! This probably wouldn't stop be from signing up to those programs, but it is useful to know what information is being tracked about you, and when!

Comment: I doubt that a program will ever be able to properly scan a legal text. Of course it can search for keywords, but you could never be sure if anything was left out. As a general rule, I always try to provide as little personal information as possible (where appropriate).

Comment: @ComFreek Yes, that's what I mean - *try* to find privacy and tracking related words. There will *never* be a program that can scan everything and find everything you want, unless you use something like AI, I guess. I only want a hint of things being tracked!

Comment: As a general rule: whenever the TOS get's too long, I sign *OFF* (and look for another place). Too long and complicated contracts IMHO are confusing, and might be setup that way with the intention to make you miss something, so I mistrust those from the beginning (guess why I still have no Paypal account, for example).

Comment: I want a program that lives my life instead of me. ;-) More seriously, I agree with your need for privacy, but don't expect a reliable program to do that. In the future, though, more and more content will be created to be machine-readable, at that time your need will be fulfilled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a service called [Terms of Service; Didn't read](http://tosdr.org/) on  which gives you a rating on terms of services. It is available as a [browser addon](http://tosdr.org/downloads.html) for Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari.

It is at least closely related to what you look for.

Comment: *It is available as a free Firefox Add-On* - Please provide a link to the addon page as well

Comment: Yes, I've clarified that and added a link directly to the download page.

Comment: It's the closest I'll get!